# AWS autoscaling group where one instance is unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an a scaling group of 2-5 instances to handle web traffic. I'm using a the `rpush` gem for push notifications, which requires a single daemon running to execute all the awaiting jobs. I'm already paying for the 2-5 instances, which have sufficient extra computing power to handle running the daemon, and I'd like to run the daemon on one of these instances.

The problem is, I can only use 1 API per auto-scaling group, so I'm having trouble finding a way to run the daemon on **only one** of the instances in the auto-scale group.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could start your daemon manually on one of the instances and mark it as [protected from termination](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/). This way it won't be terminated during scaling in. While scaling out, the default new instances will be created without the deamon.

Keep in mind that while protected from termination in the auto-scaling
group, it may still be terminated by:

> - Manual termination through the Amazon EC2 console, the
>     `terminate-instances` command, or the `TerminateInstances` action. To
>     protect Auto Scaling instances from manual termination, enable
>     termination protection. For more information, see [Enabling Termination
>     Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingDisableAPITermination) in the Amazon EC2 User Guide for Linux Instances.
> - Health check replacement if the instance fails health checks.
> - Spot Instance interruption.

(source: [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#instance-protection))